# Use timestamp in a key with useSWRInfinite()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, swr

I'm using `useSWRInfinite()` for data fetching in my React app, and on the first page I need to include the current timestamp as a cursor in the getKey function (as there's no previousPageData). I can't do it because on every millisecond the key is changing and invoking the fetcher function again. Any suggestion will sure be help!

Here is my code at the moment:

```js
const useQuestions = () => {
  const fetcher = async (url: string) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

  const timestamp = new Date().toISOString();
  const getKey = (pageIndex: number, previousPageData: any) => {
    if (previousPageData && !previousPageData.questions) return null;
    const cursorQuery = `?cursor=${pageIndex ? previousPageData?.from : timestamp}`;
    if (pageIndex && !previousPageData?.cursor) return null;
    return `/api/questions${fromQuery}`;
  };

  const { data, size, setSize, error, isLoading, isValidating, mutate } = useSWRInfinite(getKey, fetcher, {
    initialSize: 1,
    revalidateAll: true,
    revalidateFirstPage: false,
    persistSize: true,
    // I tried to set persistSize as true to prevent refetching when 1st page key is changing but no luck
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The [useMemeo](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usememo.asp) hook might help you in this case. It should stop the **key** from changing at every millisecond.

```
const useQuestions = () => {
  const fetcher = async (url: string) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

  const timestamp = useMemo(() => new Date().toISOString(), []);
  const getKey = (pageIndex: number, previousPageData: any) => {
    if (previousPageData && !previousPageData.questions) return null;
    const cursorQuery = `?cursor=${pageIndex ? previousPageData?.from : timestamp}`;
    if (pageIndex && !previousPageData?.cursor) return null;
    return `/api/questions${fromQuery}`;
  };

  const { data, size, setSize, error, isLoading, isValidating, mutate } = useSWRInfinite(getKey, fetcher, {
    initialSize: 1,
    revalidateAll: true,
    revalidateFirstPage: false,
    persistSize: true,
  });
};
```